# Using StartActivityForResult in a dynamically generated TextView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have the activity (in which the function is called), the java file holding all the functions and an activity that uses the camera to scan codes.

When the main activity loads it calls the generateTextView function which populates the page with TextViews. The onClick is enabled on all of them. When one TextView is clicked it launches the camera activity to scan a barcode. How can I send that barcode string back to the main activity, to the TextView the camera activity was launched on? I keep encountering a null object reference.

I need to tab each one of those dynamically generated TextViews and send the barcode data back to it on the main activity.

#### LayoutFile

```
public class LayoutElements extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tv;

    public TextView textViewGenerate(final Context ct, String tag, Integer id) {

        tv = new TextView(ct);

        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
        gd.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
        gd.setCornerRadius(4);
        gd.setStroke(1, 0xFF757575);

        tv.setBackground(gd);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                1.0f
        );

        //lp.height = 50;

        tv.setPadding(7, 9, 0, 0);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        tv.setTextSize(22);

        tv.setTag(tag);
        tv.setId(id);
        tv.setHint("Enter Module Serial Number");

        //Click to launch camera
        tv.setClickable(true);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent(ct, MctCameraActivity.class);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ct, MctCameraActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                //ct.startActivity(intent);
                //ToDo: finish receiving the data from the activityForResult
            }
        });

        lp.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
        lp.setMarginStart(10);
        lp.setMarginEnd(10);

        tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            String returnResult = data.getStringExtra("result");
            tv.setText(returnResult);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Error Log

`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rsscanner, PID: 16095
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4225)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at com.example.rsscanner.models.LayoutElements$1.onClick(LayoutElements.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53748248/java-lang-nullpointerexception-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-android-app-ac)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. I pass in the context from the main activity when calling this class and use it as a parameter when dynamically setting the textviews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class `LayoutElements` extends `AppCompatActivity`, but it looks like you aren't using it like an `Activity`. You cannot create an instance of an `Activity` using `new`. Only Android can instantiate Android components (`Service, Activity, BroadcastReceiver, Provider`). Your class `LayoutElements` isn't an `Activity` and should not extend `AppCompatActivity`. If you do that, you will see that `startActivityForResult()` is not defined. This is correct.

To call that method, you need to call it from the `Activity`. You could change this:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ct, MctCameraActivity.class);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

to this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MctCameraActivity.class);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

and change the method signature from:

```
public TextView textViewGenerate(final Context ct, String tag, Integer id) {
```

to:

```
public TextView textViewGenerate(final Activity activity, String tag, Integer id) {
```

Make sure that when you call `textViewGenerate()` you pass the current `Activity` as the first parameter.

NOTE: You need to move `onActivityResult()` to the actual `Activity` class that calls `textViewGenerate()`, as it will be called on the `Activity` that calls `startActivityForResult()`.

Comment: Thank you David, that sorted out my issue!